# Custom Resources Composed of Other Resources?

Tags: terraform

I'm currently working on a Terraform project to automate infrastructure in AWS. Since we are using a pretty consistent pattern, my idea was to create custom Terraform resources which are composed of multiple AWS resources to DRY things up.

Is there a way within custom Go Terraform resources which are simply composed of multiple AWS resources under the hood? I'd like to have a resource named something like `app_stack` which is composed of an auto-scaling group, an elastic load balancer, and a Route 53 name. I'd like my module to only accept a bare minimum of parameters so that it shields end-users from the implementation details.

Is this possible in Terraform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use a [Terraform module](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/index.html). A module is a collection of resources that is managed as a group.

You can expose whatever variables are necessary for the module to work, so in your case the DNS name, how many instances you want in the ASG, etc. Then when you include it in your terraform config you can specify the block, e.g:

```
module "myapp" {
  source = "./app_stack"
  dns_name = "myapp.example.com"
  instances = 5
}

module "meteordemo" {
  source = "./app_stack"
  dns_name = "meteor.example.com"
  instances = 1
}
```

[The docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/create.html) include a much more comprehensive explanation. Here are some [example modules](https://github.com/terraform-community-modules) on github for reference.

Comment: For future reference, do note that there are a lot of limitations in the Terraform HCL language, [one related to the count variable](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/3888), no support for conditional logic of any sort, etc. Writing something in Go would seem to be able to overcome this limitation, but it of course requires much more work.